# "Major" vs "majoring"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct and what is the difference?

> **Majoring** in Information Technology, xxx University
>
> **Major** in Information Technology, xxx University

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a description. For example, if you are a current student you would say:

> I am *majoring in* IT.

If you have already received your major, you might say:

> I have a *major* in IT.

This distinction works on resumes as well. As a current student, you are still *majoring* in something. If you have graduated, you already have a *major* in something.

Comment: For what it's worth, people in the US who have already graduated generally say "I *majored* in..." rather than "I have a major in..." When people talk about what degrees they've attained, I more often hear "I have a BA/BS/MA/degree in..."

Comment: @onomatomaniak So, what should i use on resume.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu On a resume, I would say name the specific type of degree, e.g. "BA in [subject]"